# "Search Everywhere" does not open in IntelliJ 2022.1

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

A few days ago, IntelliJ was updated to version 2022.1 but I noticed that the "search everywhere" double <kbd>Shift</kbd> functionality stopped working. I've tried a few things but so far without success.

Someone with the same problem?

Comment: could be caused by the **Terraform and HCL** plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-292313/2022.1-Navigation-popups-are-broken#focus=Comments-27-6008665.0-0. If you have it installed, please try upgrading it to the most recent version

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ users experience this behavior often due to a plugin which explodes through its integration with IntelliJ's Search Everywhere mechanism.

This often happens when the plugin is outdated in relation to the intellij IDE version.

**Updating the plugin is likely to solve the issue.**

(See [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010531120--Double-Shift-to-Search-Everywhere-Not-Working) thread)

An exception stack trace regarding the plugin who's messing things up will only be printed once, when intellij starts up. In the UI you're likely to notice a balloon notification regarding the plugin which have failed.

The following double shift presses which doesn't response will not emit new failures to the log.

What's confusing everybody is the fact that Search Everywhere engine could not start is not communicated properly to the user.

Comment: Had the same issue, upgrading to IntelliJ latest version fixed it.